# Trouble parsing XML with XSLT style sheet

Tags: xml, xslt, import, filemaker

I am having trouble importing XML returned by Salesforce Marketing Cloud API into a FileMaker database. I've done this with other XML sets with no issue, but this XML is different than what I have seen before. Here is an example of what comes back:

```
<Results xsi:type="DataExtensionObject">
                <PartnerKey xsi:nil="true"/>
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true"/>
                <Type>DataExtensionObject</Type>
                <Properties>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>Account</Name>
                        <Value>000000</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>LastName</Name>
                        <Value>Doe</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>FirstName</Name>
                        <Value>John</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>EmailAddress</Name>
                        <Value>email@email.net</Value>
                    </Property>
                                        <Property>
                        <Name>JobName</Name>
                        <Value>30029-Name</Value>
                    </Property>
                    <Property>
                        <Name>Primary Key</Name>
                        <Value>000000</Value>
                    </Property>
                    </Properties>
            </Results>
```

```
The multiple occurrences of the <Property> tag has me a little stumped on mapping the xpath. Any thoughts are appreciated.
```

Here is a bit of the stylesheet I tried to make work, starting with a simple attempt to just parse one field. This gets no result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tmp="http://tempuri.org" exclude-result-prefixes="SOAP-ENV tmp" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
            <!-- FIELDS -->
            <METADATA>
                <FIELD NAME="f1" TYPE="TEXT"/>              
             </METADATA>        
                <!-- DATA -->
                <RESULTSET>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Results/Properties">
                        <ROW>
                            <xsl:if test="Property/Name='Account'">
                                <COL>
                                    <DATA>
                                        <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                                    </DATA>
                                </COL>
                            </xsl:if>                                                     
                        </ROW>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </RESULTSET>
            </FMPXMLRESULT>
        </xsl:template>
    </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Your example is ambiguous. All those Property elements are obviously FIELDS that belong to the same RECORD. However, we don't know if there always will be only one record (as in your example) or if there can be more than one. If the latter, we need to see an example of at least two in order to understand how to distinguish between them.

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to import your example* would be like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <!-- FIELDS -->
        <METADATA>
            <FIELD NAME="Account"/>              
            <FIELD NAME="LastName"/>              
            <FIELD NAME="FirstName"/>              
            <FIELD NAME="EmailAddress"/>              
            <FIELD NAME="JobName"/>              
            <FIELD NAME="Primary Key"/>              
        </METADATA>        
        <!-- DATA -->
        <RESULTSET>
            <xsl:for-each select="Properties">
                <ROW>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Property[Name='Account']/Value"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Property[Name='LastName']/Value"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Property[Name='FirstName']/Value"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Property[Name='EmailAddress']/Value"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Property[Name='JobName']/Value"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                    <COL>
                        <DATA>
                            <xsl:value-of select="Property[Name='Primary Key']/Value"/>
                        </DATA>
                    </COL>
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

As I mentioned in the comment to your question, this will create a single record with 6 fields. If there can be multiple records, and each set of fields is in its own `Properties` element, then this will import them correctly too.

If every record will always have the same set of fields, listed in the same order, then you could shorten this to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/Results">
    <FMPXMLRESULT xmlns="http://www.filemaker.com/fmpxmlresult">
        <!-- FIELDS -->
        <METADATA>
            <xsl:for-each select="Properties[1]/Property">
                <FIELD NAME="{Name}"/>              
            </xsl:for-each>
        </METADATA>        
        <!-- DATA -->
        <RESULTSET>
            <xsl:for-each select="Properties">
                <ROW>
                    <xsl:for-each select="Property">
                        <COL>
                            <DATA>
                                <xsl:value-of select="Value"/>
                            </DATA>
                        </COL>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </ROW>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </RESULTSET>
    </FMPXMLRESULT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

(*) provided the missing namespace declaration for the `xsi` prefix is added.

Comment: Michael, thank you! Each file will have multiple records, all with same field names. However, different files will have different fields names and quantities. That's why I was keeping the field names in the table generic. The xslt sheet will be generated dynamically for each download prior to import. This gives me a lot to work with. Appreciated!

Comment: I suspect you could use the 2nd version for all your types.